# Can I install git in aws Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am making a serverless service using aws lambda. I am using python as a handler. The problem occurred in one of the libraries that my service will use. This library invokes git with subprocess.Popen (), which causes an error because git does not work in aws lambda. This library is the core of my service and must be used. So I'm thinking of a scenario where I install git on lambda every time I call the lambda function.
Have you ever installed something on lambda?
(yum will not install because of an error)

Comment: Why don't you package everything (all your dependencies) in the zip file and upload it to Lambda? You can install any dependency you need in the zip.

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure: I did not yet install anything on aws lambda. The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html) say that you should be able to use yum to get git working. I would talk to their support if that is failing. It would be the easiest way to get it installed. However, have a look at [this document](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/). It basically says you can put the binaries you need in a .zip file and upload. So The way to go about it would be to compile git in an Amazon Linux environment (spin up a EC2 instance), then upload the binary to your Lambda environment. The third option would be to execute git remotely, but I don't know whether that is possible in your use case.

Comment: Can you cite more specifically where yum is mentioned in the context of adding things to the Lambda runtime environment?  That seems counter-intuitive and I don't see it documented.  Compiling and adding to the zip file is the correct solution, but the best solution is probably using [a specific source image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html) for your build environment, rather than Amazon Linux generally.

Comment: this should be marked as the correct answer, Lambda is a sandboxed env, you can upload your own binaries as this answer states.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do what you need with the GitPython module. (https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html). Create a requirements.txt file in the root of your lambda function directory and list your modules in there (including gitpython). Then run pip install -r requirements.txt -t . So that it installs all the packages into that directory. Then zip up the folder and upload to the lambda function.

Comment: It doesn't work that way too.